# FabricJS - Skewing an image using corners

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to create an app where a user can "skew" an image using the four corner grab handles. I have this working with a standard polygon, but cannot get it to work using an image. I'm a complete Canvas/Fabric noob, so no idea where to start.

https://jsfiddle.net/09qtbs85/

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var points = [{"x":10,"y":10},{"x":10,"y":60},{"x":100,"y":60}, {"x":100,"y":10}]

var img = fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/XMVWqfo.jpeg', function(myImg)
{
  canvas.add(myImg);
});

var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points,
{
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
  fill: '#FEE04E',
  scaleX: 4,
  scaleY: 4,
  objectCaching: false,
  transparentCorners: true,
  cornerColor: '#000000',
});
canvas.viewportTransform = [0.7, 0, 0, 0.7, -50, 50];
canvas.add(polygon);

function polygonPositionHandler(dim, finalMatrix, fabricObject)
{
 var x = (fabricObject.points[this.pointIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x),
     y = (fabricObject.points[this.pointIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y);
 return fabric.util.transformPoint({ x: x, y: y }, fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices(fabricObject.canvas.viewportTransform, fabricObject.calcTransformMatrix()));
}

function actionHandler(eventData, transform, x, y)
{
 var polygon = transform.target,
     currentControl = polygon.controls[polygon.__corner],
     mouseLocalPosition = polygon.toLocalPoint(new fabric.Point(x, y), 'center', 'center'),
     polygonBaseSize = polygon._getNonTransformedDimensions(),
     size = polygon._getTransformedDimensions(0, 0),
     finalPointPosition = {x: mouseLocalPosition.x * polygonBaseSize.x / size.x + polygon.pathOffset.x, y: mouseLocalPosition.y * polygonBaseSize.y / size.y + polygon.pathOffset.y};
 polygon.points[currentControl.pointIndex] = finalPointPosition;
 return true;
}

function anchorWrapper(anchorIndex, fn)
{
 return function(eventData, transform, x, y)
 {
  var fabricObject = transform.target,
      absolutePoint = fabric.util.transformPoint({x: (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x), y: (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y)}, fabricObject.calcTransformMatrix()),
      actionPerformed = fn(eventData, transform, x, y),
      newDim = fabricObject._setPositionDimensions({}),
      polygonBaseSize = fabricObject._getNonTransformedDimensions(),
      newX = (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x) / polygonBaseSize.x,
      newY = (fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y) / polygonBaseSize.y;
  fabricObject.setPositionByOrigin(absolutePoint, newX + 0.5, newY + 0.5);
  return actionPerformed;
 }
}

function Edit()
{
 var poly = canvas.getObjects()[0];
 canvas.setActiveObject(poly);
 poly.edit = !poly.edit;
 if(poly.edit)
 {
  var lastControl = poly.points.length - 1;
  poly.cornerStyle = 'circle';
  poly.cornerColor = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';
  poly.controls = poly.points.reduce(function(acc, point, index)
  {
   acc['p' + index] = new fabric.Control(
   {
    positionHandler: polygonPositionHandler,
    actionHandler: anchorWrapper(index > 0 ? index - 1 : lastControl, actionHandler),
    actionName: 'modifyPolygon',
    pointIndex: index
   });
   return acc;
  }, { });
 }
 else
 {
  poly.cornerColor = 'blue';
  poly.cornerStyle = 'rect';
  poly.controls = fabric.Object.prototype.controls;
 }
 poly.hasBorders = !poly.edit;
 canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas
{
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-CeIsOAsgJnmevfCi2C7Zsyy6bQKi43utIjdA87Q0ZY84oDqnI0uwfM9+bKiIkI75lUeI00WG/+uJzOmuHlesMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<body onload="Edit();">
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

I need the image to be able to be resized just like the yellow rectangle can be (then the rectangle will be removed)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Well polygons and images aren't exactly "apples to apples". Polygons are points with lines connecting them, raster images (JPEGs and PNGs, for instance) are NOT; they're like square waffles that you fill each waffle hole with different color syrups. So it makes sense why you can move the points on the polygon, and "skew" it (though that's not necessarily the case).

Comment: I don't think there is a native way to accomplish this. You'd have to write some serious code to borrow from the polygon class (making sure that it always has 4 points), overlay the image from the image class, then compute a transformation matrix for each quadrant of the polygon (corner to center point) and then apply it to each quadrant of the the image. Good luck.